# opera/chrome context menu in the url bar/omnibar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, address-bar, opera-extension

With Opera, I'm playing with the example extension that looks up a selected text using the contextMenu. I would like to add a menu entry in the contextMenu when the user right click in the address-bar (url-bar, omnibox and so on) I have tried 
In the manifest:

```
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
         "16": "icon_16.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Context Menu API - Search Selected Text"   
},
```

and in the background script:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Look url up: \"%s\"",
    contexts: ["page_action"],
    onclick: searchText
});
```

But without success. Is that possible ? am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks
F.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can only use the `%s` template when the context is `"selection"` within the document.

Also, right-clicks on the omnibar would never be routed to your extension - there isn't a context for that.

In Chrome 49+, the Page Action is the icon your extension gets in the toolbar. Previously (and, supposedly, currently in Opera) it was an icon inside the omnibox itself - but you had to expressly "show" it for each page. Only right-clicks on that icon count as `"page_action"` context.